# String interpolation with concatenation match

Tags: elixir

Why does this code work this way? Is there a way to use accomplish what I want to with `bar` in this way?? (I know there are alternatives to doing pattern matching a string)

```
# Elixir 1.3.4
defmodule MyMod do

  @foo "abc"

  def concatenation_operator_with_interpolation do
    bar = "abc"

    "#{@foo}::" <> matchworks = "abc::xyz"
    IO.puts matchworks # xzy

    "#{bar}::" <> matchbroke = "abc::xyz" # cannot invoke remote function String.Chars.to_string/1 inside match
    IO.puts matchbroke # never runs
  end

end

MyMod.concatenation_operator_with_interpolation
```

Comment: Must have something to do with the string interpolation.  I can reproduce this with `"#{bar}" = "abc"`.

Comment: `bar = "abc"; size = byte_size(bar); <<^bar::binary-size(size)>> <> matchworks = "abc::xyz"`

Comment: Yea, I'm wondering if there is something I can do to the make the interpolation work. The above isn't quite as concise... you know?

Comment: I should have known you'd know how to fix this @Dogbert :)

Comment: @TheWorkerAnt As far as I know, there isn't, but you can probably write a macro if you're going to use this kind of pattern a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: you need to store the size of `bar` and then do `<<^bar::binary-size(size)>> <> matchworks = "abc::xyz"`:

```
iex(1)> bar = "abc"
"abc"
iex(2)> size = byte_size(bar)
3
iex(3)> <<^bar::binary-size(size)>> <> matchworks = "abc::xyz"
"abc::xyz"
iex(4)> matchworks
"::xyz"
iex(5)> <<^bar::binary-size(size)>> <> matchworks = "ab::xyz"
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: "ab::xyz"
```

Long answer: in a binary match involving concatenation, all the binaries except the last one on the LHS must either be a constant value known at compile time or have an explicit size value.

In the first case (which works for you), Elixir evaluates the interpolation at compile time since all the expressions inside are compile time constants, and replaces it with something like `"abc" <> matchworks = "abc::xyz"`, which works fine.

In the second case, `bar` is a variable and therefore `"#{bar}"` can have any value at runtime, so you need to specify a size explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! Your description of why the constant works makes perfect sense.